# How to create a month dropdown in "MM" format in asp.net MVC razor view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to loop through months of year with MM format , i do it but months format is 1, 2, 3, ...etc i want the format to be 01, 02, 03 
how i do it

```
<select id="CreditCardExpiryDateMonth" class="dropdown form-control">
    @for (var iMonth = DateTime.Now.Month; iMonth <= 12; iMonth++)
    {
        <option value="@iMonth"@(DateTime.Now.Month == iMonth ? " selected" : "")>@iMonth</option>
    }
</select>
```

any advice

Comment: You if it's currently September, you want to show all 12 months, but you want September to be first in the list?

Comment: Do you want the value or the text to be in the format?  Or both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ToString` to format the int.

```
<select id="CreditCardExpiryDateMonth" class="dropdown form-control">
     @for (var iMonth = 1; iMonth <= 12; iMonth++)
     {
         <option value="@iMonth"@(DateTime.Now.Month == iMonth ? " selected" : "")>@iMonth.ToString("00")</option>
     }
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using MVC, you can use `SelectList` and [`Html.DropdownList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc) helpers to populate your dropdown and pre-select a value:

```
@Html.DropDownList("CreditCardExpiryDateMonth",
    new SelectList(Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(a => new { Text = a.ToString("00"), Value = a }),
                        "Value", 
                        "Text", 
                        DateTime.Today.Month),
    new { @class = "dropdown form-control" })
```

How this works:

- `@Html.DropDownList("CreditCardExpiryDateMonth")`: Creates a `select` element with name and id as: "CreditCardExpiryDateMonth"
- The second parameter in this overload of `DropDownList` is the `SelectList`. We usually get this from the database and assign to `ViewBag` in the controller. But in your case, we can use the [`Enumerable.Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to generate 12 numbers and format them to proper strings. In this overload of the `SelectList`, 4th parameter is the `selectedValue`. This is used to pre-select a value in the dropdown. In your case, it is Today's month.
- The final parameter is the `htmlAttributes`. Here, we add `class` to the select element.

This approach is flexible and cleaner. Should your requirement change to displaying month names with globalization or something else, you only have to change the `SelectList` logic.

Answer (score -1):

To make the format MM or 01 etc, try this:

```
DateTime.Now.Month.ToString("d2")
```

Comment: OP needs `iMonth` (an `int`) formatted as two digits, not `DateTime.Now`.